# Index file drastically slows page loading time

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, load

I'm trying my hardest to get this site's load time blazing fast. I've taken good steps in caching. Every static element on the page is cached so it renders immediately. My page loads in 1 second, because of the index file:

[image]
How can I cut down the load time of this index file. I questioned yesterday, and the answer worked on my localhost, but I'm now on the server.

Here's the site:
http://thenozzle.net/login

username: admin1
password: admin1

Please troubleshoot this. Sites like youtube, Facebook and google have this element loading in 400 ms. How can I do this?

Both my server and I are on the west coast U.S.

Comment: Your page loads 3.7Mb of data

Comment: Actually yes, [here](http://www.marketingexperiments.com/improving-website-conversion/page-weight.html) and [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) are some recommendations on page weight and speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a few tests and the average load of index is 700ms for me. Are you using any server side technology? php, mysql? There are quite a lot of reasons for a site being slow.

First check if creating a completely empty html page takes 700ms or something around there. If it does, then your server has some latency issues. Id recommend talking with your host provider and see what they suggest.

If it works fine and you are using server side technology, use simple tests to benchmark each part of your website. (set a timer before the first line of code and another after certain operation, then subtract the later from the former, you end up with specific data of how long each part took)

Otherwise follow Vap0r suggestion, maybe that helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Without ANYTHING on the page, it still took around 500ms to load, that's only 200ms shorter. And the favicon took twice as long, I'm not sure why. I'm using iPage. Anyone know how good they are?

Comment: Not sure about iPage, never even heard of em. But it look like it is  server side (before your page is even served to the user) maybe iPage adds some sort of overhead to track stats and such. Or the server is just super busy all the time :S 

I use Dreamhost (not the most reliable all the time but) my website with a tiny simple html page loads in 58ms. Take a look: http://roleland.com/ (ignore the time to load the images lol)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest changing your `cache-control` header? I don't do this much, but with a load time of 680ms, your site worked quite well. But, if you'd like, here's some info on [modifying cache control for efficiency](http://www.1918.com/speeding-up-your-site/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be server side. I would recommend using a profiler such as [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to see what is taking the longest time, then try to optimize that. Feel free to ask follow-up questions on that.

Comment: Feel free to elaborate on how the OP can use xdebug to do that debugging and profiling!